# What may cause all UIView animations to finish instantly?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, animation, uiview, ios8

I have an iOS app where I use a lot of UIView animations. They'll all work perfectly for a very long time, then suddenly all animations finish instantly instead of using the specified duration. No errors and the app still functions, but the animations don't work properly.

The app will do a lot of downloading small graphic files in the background then call a selector on the main thread to present the graphics.

Does anyone know what may cause this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not okay to handle UIKit in backgrounnd threads but thought it was limited to all drawing, like adding subviews etc. It seems creating and changing views (without adding them as subviews) is not okay either. My problem in particular was creating UIImageViews in a background thread. I changed the code to load into UIImages and create the UIImageViews in the presentation code, which is run in the main thread and now it's completely stable.